# Model with piecewise-linear functions

Tags: multiple-regression, diagnostic, piecewise-linear

I have a model which is of the following deterministic form:

Y = A + B + C

A, B and C are piecewise-linear functions of a, b and c, which are macroeconomic variables. I have the values (nodes, slopes) for all the segments of these PWLFs.

I need to run diagnostics (assumption tests, performance tests etc.) on this model.  I am not sure how to proceed with this model. What would be the assumptions underlying this model. How shall I formally compare it with an alternate model that is simply a multiple linear regression of Y on a,b and c?

Comment: The trickiest part will be how to treat the nodes -- are they fixed, or do you determine their values from the data? In the former case, this is an example of a generalized linear model (GLM). If you search for this keyword (in web and text resources) you'll find a number of methods of comparing these models. In the latter case, this is a more general class of problem (similar to  a generalized additive model (GAM)). How did you produce the node values?

Comment: Since your variables $A,B,C$ are completely defined, how does this question differ from any other multiple regression?

Comment: @jwimberley nodes are fixed so I suppose I should be lookingup for generalized linear model. I am not sure how nodes were arrived at, I suspect these are based on manual judgments.